# How do I prevent printing hidden "_method" field by CakePHP FormHelper?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, formhelper

I'm creating a form with the FormHelper that will be posting data to an 3rd party.
The 3rd party checks a SHA-1 hash that I'm sending along, which is based on the form fields and its values + a passphrase.

I'd like to prevent the FormHelper from printing the "_method" field, it is an unexpected value by the 3rd party and it will mess up my hash.
How do I do that?

Please not: I do understand the purpose of the field, though it only serves a purpose when posting back to CakePHP. In this case I'm posting to a third party.

kind regards,
Bart

Answer (score 1):

There no setting to disable it, as the FormHelper is used to post to Cake again in 99.9% of all cases.

However, from looking at he source code ( https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L403 ) it looks like you could pass in a type that is not "delete", "post" or "put" and it will not create such a hidden field. But since you needed a valid value here, I would not do that.

The other option would be to not use the form helper, or adjust the FormHelper as extended class which overwrites this specific method to get your desired output.